# MyPy: "Callable[[], Connection]" has no attribute "_db" [attr-defined]

Tags: python, sqlite3, mypy

У меня есть следующий код

```py
def get_db() -> sqlite3.Connection:
    if hasattr(get_db, "_db"):
        return get_db._db

    db_file = config.SQLITE_DB_FILE
    connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    # connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    get_db._db = connection
    return connection
```

И когда я хочу использовать типизацию для функции *(`->sqlite3.Connection:`)*, MyPy показывает ошибку `"Callable[[], Connection]" has no attribute "_db" [attr-defined]` в строке `get_db ._db = connection`.

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: переведите свой вопрос на русский язык, как это требуют правила данного сообщества

Comment: @ZxNuClear Извини, хотел сначала написать на своем языке и перевести, но забыл и опубликовал вопрос. Все исправил